# ApplicationContextAware injecting the prototype object in the singleton object

Tags: java, spring

i am trying to inject a prototype object in the singleton class..

```
public class Triangle implements ApplicationContextAware{
private Point pointA;
private ApplicationContext context=null;
Point point=(Point)context.getBean("pointA",Point.class);
public void draw(){
    System.out.println("The prototype point A is ("+point.getX()+","+point.getY()+")");
}
@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
    throws BeansException {
this.context=context;

}
}
```

i created a Point java file with the co-ordinates x and y..

when i tried to compile the above code i get the following errors

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [Spring.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.david.shape.Triangle]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Post web.xml as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private ApplicationContext context=null;
Point point=(Point)context.getBean("pointA",Point.class);
```

You're calling `getBean()` on `context` which is, obviously, null.

The context will only be initialized by Spring after the Triangle bean has been constructed, and after its `setApplicationContext()` method has been called by Spring. Only then, you can call `getBean()` on the context.

BTW, you're not doing dependency injection here. You're doing dependency lookup, which is exactly what dependency injection frameworks like Spring are used to avoid. To inject your point, just do

```
public class Triangle {

    private Point pointA;

    @Autowired
    public Triangle(@Qualifier("pointA") Point pointA) {
        this.pointA = pointA;
    }

    ...
}
```